# Error in Rx runtime

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, system.reactive

I've developed a component that uses Reactive Extensions to handle data from a serial port. When I run an app that uses my component, the app stops workng and in the Application Event Log I find this error:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Stack:
   at System.Reactive.ScheduledObserver`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Dispatch(System.Reactive.Disposables.ICancelable)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.b__32(System.Action`1, System.Reactive.Disposables.ICancelable)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.NewThreadScheduler+c__DisplayClass3`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].b__2()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

None of my code appears in that stack trace, so I'm not sure how to debug this. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Whoops meant to add that as a comment not an answer. You probably wont see it on your stack because it is on the NewThreadScheduler, it's occurring asynchronously on a different thread stack

Comment: I guess the exception is getting marshaled back to the main thread somehow.  Anyway, as I mentioned in another comment, I seem to have found the problem... I was trying to wait on a ManualResetEvent with a negative timeout (actually TimeSpan.MinValue, which for some reason I thought would be 0, but is in fact a large negative number).

Comment: As an aside I would also not recommend introducing additional a synchronicity in an `onNext` method it'll get messy really fast and it is generally not recommended to throw from an observer.

Comment: Can you please show the code you're running? Just showing the exception and the stack isn't enough.